# Is it possible to make vim not show blue text

Tags: ubuntu, vim

I've installed Ubuntu,

And they have decided to use blue text for comments in vim, 
Blue is the worst color to use for text, as human eyes have the least number of receptors for blue, one thing I remember from college.

Is it possible to tell vim never use blue?
I don't want to install a new color theme or anything, because I like the syntax coloring they have for every thing, I can even see correct syntax in Apache's httpd.conf

So I need a simple change, blue to gray or something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Append this line to your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
hi Comment ctermfg=DarkRed
```

You can find the list of available colornames in the help section: `:help cterm-colors`.

Answer (score 1):

Reconfigure your terminal instead. Under *Edit → Profile Preferences → Colors*, you can edit the palette used.

Note however that this only works for 16-color mode. In 256-color mode, such a task is impossible, since neither Vim nor the terminal have any way of knowing which colors are to be considered "blue" or "not blue" or in-between...

Comment: Thanks, but I'm sshing into the server it's not an xwindow

Comment: @[user893730](http://superuser.com/users/106494/user893730), that means its more like the 16-color mode @[grawity](http://superuser.com/users/1686/grawity) has mentioned. You've to tweak the terminal emulator preferences. Which could be : Settings for `gnome-terminal` or `konsole` or putty (if you ssh *from* windows) or `xterm/rxvt/aterm` (these, by setting colors resources in `.Xdefaults` file) and many more.

Comment: @Anil: 256-color mode is not related to X11 or SSH at all. It is a terminal emulator function, available on all platforms (for example, PuTTY on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

Type `:highlight` to see a list of all colors and then change the ones that are blue with `highlight NAME ctermfg=COLOR` (put it in ~/.vimrc). For graphical vim you would use `highlight NAME guifg=COLOR` instead.